# Have Up button act the same as android back button

Tags: android

My android application has the following activity flow

Listing -> Buy -> Sell
From the listing when an item is clicked/selected an id is passed to buy to pull the relevant data from the server. If a user owns a certain item there will be a sell  option as well from the buy screen (which doubles as an overview of said item).

The problem I am facing is that when you are on the sell screen and press the android back button you are taken back to the buy screen in it's original state, however when you click the back arrow (up) from the activity in the toolbar, it seems that it is actually trying to launch a new activity and throws an exception (since the activity cannot know what the id was). The buy activity is listed as a parent to the sell activity in the manifest.

I need to somehow make the up button to act the same as the back button on this particular activity, or at least pass the id back somehow.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just yesterday i did this for my app. This is what I did:

In `manifest` file I removed

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.app.MainActivity" />
```

that was part of my `DetailsActivity`.

In the `DetailsActivity` I added this line to `onCreate`

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and in `onOptionsItemSelected()` method I added these lines

```
 if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
```

Not sure if it is the best way to handle this but oh well it works :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond help me solve my issue. This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an `ActionBar` (either platform or AppCompat) override the following method in the activity from which you wish to go back.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull final MenuItem item) {
    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This should be safe to use in a simple navigation hierarchy such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity, `onOptionsItemSelected()` method get the clicked item `id`, if the `id` is `android.R.id.home` then just `finish()` current activity.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```